# Simple parallelisation for hashset

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, hashset, parallel.foreach

I have 2 loops(nested), trying to do a simple parallelisation

**pseudocode**:

```
for item1 in data1 (~100 million row)
    for item2 in data2 (~100 rows)
        result = process(item1,item2) // couple of if conditions
        hashset.add(result) // while adding, incase of a duplicate i also decide wihch one to retain
```

`process(item1,item2)` to be precise has 4 if conditions bases on values in item1 and item2.(time taken is less than 50ms)

`data1` size is Nx17
`data2` size is Nx17
`result` size is 1x17 (result is joined into a string before it is added into hashset)

max output size: unknown, but i would like to be ready for atleast 500 million
which means the hashset would be holding 500 million items. (how to handle so much data in a hashset would be an another question i guess)

Should i just use a `concurrent hashset` to make it thread safe and go with `parallel.each` or should i go with `TASK` concept

Please provide some code samples based on your opinion.

Comment: The problem of how to parallelize `data1` would seem to be more interesting than any consideration of how you store the results, or the exact flavor of parallelism employed. Retrieving and storing 100 million rows is likely to be a significant sequential bottleneck if left as-is.

Comment: I would recommand `parallel.foreach` because it takes into account how many core the system has. If you would to spawn `~100 mil * 100` task it would be a huge overhead of managment, which is a waste of resources

Comment: Your code example is not clear. Should it be process(item1, item2)? Otherwise why the loops?

Comment: What is the number of the anticipated unique results? In other words, how many items do you expect that will be stored in the `HashSet` after the completion of the whole operation?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias :question updated to reflect your question. answer is dont know yet, but would like to be ready atleast for 500 million

Comment: @jira : sorry my bad. question updated

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends a lot on the costs of `process(data1, data2)`.  If this is a CPU-intensive operation, then you can surely benefit from `Parallel.ForEach`. Of course, you should use concurrent dictionary, or lock around your hash table.  You should benchmark to see what works best for you.  If `process` has too little impact on performance, then probably you will get nothing from the parallelization - the locking on the hashtable will kill it all.

You should also try to see whether enumerating data2 on the outer loop is also faster.  It might give you another benefit - you can have a separate hashtable for each instance of data2 and then merge the results into one hashtable.  This will avoid locks.

Again, you need to do your tests, there is no universal answer here.

Comment: Yup that is exactly where i got a bit confused, since ```process(item1,item2)``` isnt a CPU intensive action, putting walls around Hashset might kill the parallelisation advantage. So coming to your enumeration approach, how does enumeration help exactly ? i am bit new to these concepts, pardon my ignorance. but i am up for experimenting.

Comment: The enumeration advise is applicable only if you try to parallelize.  Since `process(item1, item2)` is a cheap operation for you, you might not even bother trying further.  Try with `Parallel.For` and `ConcurrentDictionary` and see the results for yourself.  It may have benefit, it may not, more likely it may not. :-)

Comment: is there any reason why u suggested concurrentdictionary over concurrent hashset ?

Comment: No.  Depends on whether you need just a list of of hashes, or hash -> value. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to separate the processing of the data from the saving of the results to the `HashSet`, because the first is parallelizable but the second is not. You could achieve this separation with the producer-consumer pattern, using a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) and threads (or tasks). But I'll show a solution using a more specialized tool, the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. I'll assume that the data are two arrays of integers, and the processing function can produce up to 500,000,000 different results:

```
var data1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100_000_000).ToArray();
var data2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();

static int Process(int item1, int item2)
{
    return unchecked(item1 * item2) % 500_000_000;
}
```

The dataflow pipeline will have two blocks. The first block is a [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2) that accepts an item from the `data1` array, processes it with all items of the `data2` array, and returns a batch of the results (as an `int` array).

```
var processBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int[]>(item1 =>
{
    int[] batch = new int[data2.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < data2.Length; j++)
    {
        batch[j] = Process(item1, data2[j]);
    }
    return batch;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    BoundedCapacity = 100,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 // Configurable
});
```

The second block is and [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) that receives the processed batches from the first block, and adds the individual results in the `HashSet`.

```
var results = new HashSet<int>();
var saveBlock = new ActionBlock<int[]>(batch =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < batch.Length; i++)
    {
        results.Add(batch[i]);
    }
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    BoundedCapacity = 100,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 // Mandatory
});
```

The line below links the two blocks together, so that the data will flow automatically from the first block to the second:

```
processBlock.LinkTo(saveBlock,
    new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

The last step is to feed the first block with the items of the `data1` array, and wait for the completion of the whole operation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data1.Length; i++)
{
    processBlock.SendAsync(data1[i]).Wait();
}
processBlock.Complete();
saveBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

The `HashSet` contains now the results.

A note about using the [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) option. This option controls the flow of the data, so that a fast block upstream will not flood with data a slow block downstream. Configuring properly this option increases the memory and CPU efficiency
of the pipeline.

The TPL Dataflow library is built-in the .NET Core, and available as a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) for .NET Framework.

Comment: can u explain "This option controls the flow of the data, so that a fast block upstream will not flood with data a slow block downstream. "

Comment: @dreamer yeap. The dataflow blocks have one or two internal buffers, where they store the incoming data and the processed data (the `ActionBlock` has no output, so it has only one buffer). By default these buffers are unbounded. So if you push data to a block at a rate higher than the rate it can process these data, its input buffer will grow larger and larger, eventually leading to an `OutOfMemoryException`. The same will happen if the processed data are removed from the block at a slower rate than they are produced.

Comment: @dreamer usually the total amount of data that are passing though a pipeline are not that much, so configuring the `BoundedCapacity` is not important, but in your case the workload is huge. Unfortunately configuring the `BoundedCapacity` adds some complications regarding exceptions. A faulted block downstream will stop consuming the data produced by the upstream block, so the healthy block will stop producing more data waiting for someone to consume the already produced data. Hopefully your code will be error-free, so that you don't have to deal with these complications.